# What about a "visible only to responder/poster" option in stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

My suggestion is, since a discussion between the question poster and the responder about the details(happens a lot when the responder doesn't fully understand what the poster wants) such as

> Who posted the Q: "I mean ..."
>
> Responder : "I have updated the answer"

And this happened to be useless for others. **Making a visible-to-XX-only would make it more legible.**

Comment: Probably other responders would have the same questions too, so it may be good to keep it public, IMHO.

Comment: I think this would not only give a way for posters and responders to hide something they know it would be useless to anyone else but the recipient but keep the post straight forward to them, but also a potential solution to the controversial **Thank-you-note**.

Comment: How do you moderate those invisible comments (e.g. if it's not a thank-you-note but a f*-you note that's sent)? Would diamond mods have to review all them without any help from other users?

Comment: @Mat I think that's what **flag** is for. I mean, we do have things we want to post on the comment, which we do know it won't be helpful to others in the community, but will make the thread more readable for the poster and the responder.

Comment: You need 15rep to flag (and you need to understand how that works/know that it exists). Comments are hard enough to moderate already, you're bringing in a whole new avenue for abuse that can only be monitored by 1 poster and diamond mods.

Comment: wait..... stack is not meant just for one user. it's meant to be a permanent repo of questions and answers. Putting anything hidden is bad, period. If it's helpful to you, and we aim to make a Q&A that will be helpful to future visitor, then it doesn't make sense to make any of this private.  If you want to say "thank you", upvote/accept an answer :)

Comment: Most of the use case for this would be handled by [this M.SE idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/274165).

Comment: The reaction to this proposal is a perfect example of the pathological inability of Meta to ever agree on anything. Of course even if there was widespread agreement nothing would happen anyway, so who actually cares?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm calling this the Kazoo problem, and it's a fundamental problem that leaving text boxes around the Internet creates.

To illustrate this, I'm calling the following thing a magic trumpet of knowledge. You should blow on it only when you have something *amazing* to bring into this realm, otherwise you waste the magic essence that follows and surrounds it in light:

[image: It's freaking magical]

Now the ***rest*** of the Internet comes along and says ...

> *Hey look! A kazoo full of glitter!!!! Row, row, row your boat, gently down the stream!!! Ooooh colors, look at all the colooors!!!!*

Clearly, we've yet to find a way to differentiate what we call 'comments' from everything else on the Internet called 'comments'. At the same time, we've yet to wrap our head around a design for better moderation tools to manage them.

The fix for this is to *fix what's really wrong*, hiding them as you suggest is just hiding the larger problem, and doesn't fit at all into the very public & transparent nature of the site.

Comment: The point of this kazoo analogy escapes me. Anyway, are you going to share with us *what's really wrong*?

Answer (score 8):

I don't like the suggestion, for a couple of reasons:

- As [@Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291751/what-about-a-visible-only-to-responder-poster-option-in-stackoverflow/291756#comment183803_291751), "private" messages like that are difficult to moderate. How often a comment gets flagged can be used as a indication of it's quality. I've seen *extremely bad* comments get deleted in no time because of this. This feature adds content to the site that only a handful of people can even see.
- If one of the parties decides to post publicly ((un)intentionally), there'd be a one-sided conversation on a post.
- I fail to see the benefits of adding this feature. Sure, "Thanks" comments could be posted privately then, but you can't force people to do so. All it seems to do to me, is complicate the way you post comments.

Comment: The second point and about complicating the system is quite convincing, though I don't agree with the rest. I think making a question more readable, especially for newbies like me, would make us feel we can make an effort to make it better for the community.

Answer (score 2):

This goes against one of the fundamental premises of SO: Content is expected to be beneficial to *everybody*, not just the poster of the question.

Now, I know you're only proposing to hide some comments, and comments are secondary relative to questions and answers. Still, the clarifying comment dialog that sometimes follows answers can be beneficial to other readers, and provide helpful supporting information. In addition, others can jump in and help get the open issues with the answer resolved if they see the comments.

I also share the moderation concerns that Cerbrus already pointed out in an earlier answer. SO relies heavily on community moderation, and content that can only be seen by a small subset of users (and diamond mods) cannot be dealt with by the community.

The only clear cut case where I would find the proposed feature useful is the "I updated the answer" comments that are made solely to ping the OP. But I think there are better solutions for this scenario. First of all, the comment can be deleted once it has served its purpose. Also, while I'm pretty sure this has been discussed and rejected before, I still like the idea of automatically notifying the OP when an answer has been edited.